# How can I calculate the derivative of the derivative using the tangent line?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, graphing-functions

How can I calculate the derivative of the derivative of a function $ f(x) $ using the tangent line of a point from that function $ f(x) $ ?

Comment: If you ONLY know the line tangent to the graph of a function at some point you CANNOT determine the derivative of the derivative (that is, the second derivative). There are many functions that are tangent to a line at a given point which have different second derivatives. To see this draw a simple line, fix a point and draw many curves tangent to it, the derivative of the derivative is the rate at which the growth (or decrease) rate changes. Could you provide more information about your question?

Answer (score 2):

If you ONLY know the line tangent to the graph of a function at some point you CANNOT determine the derivative of the derivative (that is, the second derivative). There are many functions that are tangent to a line at a given point which have different second derivatives. To see this draw a simple line, fix a point and draw many curves tangent to it, the derivative of the derivative is the rate at which the growth (or decrease) rate changes.

For example, the family of functions $x^2,x^4,x^6,...$ they all have the real line $y=0$ as tangent line at the point $x=0$, but their second derivatives are $2x, 4x^3, 6x^5...$ respectively.

However, if you knew the tangent line at EVERY point or at least around some point of interest $p$, then it'd be possible to calculate the second derivative. If $m(x)$ denotes the slope of the tangent line at a point $x$, then the second derivative at a point $p$ is simply (if it exists)
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{m(p+h)-m(p)}{h}$$

**EDIT:** a better example is given by a comment to this answer below.

Comment: There should be: $2, 12x^2, 30x^4,\ldots$. But actually for $x=0$ the second derivatives are: $2,0,0,0,\ldots$. A better example would be a family of functions $cx^2$ for $c\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Indeed, thanks.